# Swagger UI does not show the response body

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am sending error response 400 and 500 with response body content. I don't see the response on my swagger UI, but i see it when i run the query using other tools ex: curl or postman.

Am i missing something in the swagger json/yaml file

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI - 2 or 3? If 3, this looks like a known issue, [#3072](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3072).

Comment: Just in case - are there any errors in the browser console (F12)?

Comment: @Helen I am using version 2. Yes, there is a error, i am sending error code 500, that's the error on console

Comment: Is your issue the same as https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3041?

Comment: @Helen Yes, that's the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3072) was fixed in Swagger UI 3.0.18.